# Add RTL to ListView.builder horizontal flutter

Tags: flutter

I am trying to make `ListView.builder` horizontal scrolling from right to left

My code:

```
SliverToBoxAdapter(
  child: Container(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 4.5,
    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 5.0, top: 10.0),
    child: ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
        return InkWell(/* ... */)
      }
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to add reverse parameter to the ListView

here is an example:

```
ListView.builder(
    reverse: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
    itemCount: list.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, position) {
      return Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Text(list[position]),
          color: Colors.grey,
          height: 10,
          width: 10,
        ),
      );
    },
  )
```

Comment: still you are looking for answer?

Comment: what do u mean ? I just answered it @satish

Comment: @BaselAbuhadrous Thanks very mush , it's work reverse: true,

Comment: That's I am asking, is solution given by is working or not?@Basel Abuhadrous .

Comment: It doesn't work for me...  '-'

Comment: I think I should refer to my codes as usual..

Answer (score 0):

**for horizontal**

```
ListView.builder(
    reverse: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
```

**for vertical**

```
ListView.builder(
    reverse: true,
    scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
```

Answer (score 0):

best way to make it is to wrap your ListView with `Directionality` widget with `TextDirection.rtl`
like following code

```
Directionality(
   textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
   child: ListView.builder(
      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
      itemCount: list.length,
      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
         return InkWell(/* ... */)
      }
   ),
);
```